# Issue with char pointer being assigned to another location and using strcpy()?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Here i'm trying to replace the word "how are you" in string array 's' by "woo". But it is exiting abruptly during the runtime . please help

```
char *s[] = {"hi there","how are you","Fine Ok!"};
char str1[4] = "how" ;char str2[4] = "woo";
char *j = NULL; //(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
int i,k; char n[100] = "hi";
//printf("%d",strlen(s));
for(i = 0;i<3;i++ )
{
    j = strstr(s[i],str1);
    if(j==0)
    continue;
    else
    {
        printf("j is %s",j);
        printf("j is %s",j+10);
        strcpy(j,str2);

        printf("j is %s",j);
        break;
    }
}
printf("%s",s[1]);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems in your code.  Lets start with one of the more obvious: Remember that `strcpy` adds the string terminator. You might want to use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) instead:

```
memcpy(j, str2, strlen(str2));
```

To continue, you allocate memory and assign it to `j`, then in the loop you *reassign* to `j` making `j` point somewhere else, and you loose the original memory you have allocated leading to a memory leak. Also, [in C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Lastly, and the probable cause of your crash: You try to modify a string literal, and all string literals are *read only*.

Comment: i just removed the malloc to avoid unnecessary confusion. I've tried using memcopy but ended with the same error.

Comment: Ah yes!  *s[] is a read only literal. I've overlooked it. Thanks